# Handling Vectors of Textures/Sprites @ SMFL

Tags: c++, textures, sprite

This is basically the [White Square Problem](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem) when vectors of textures and sprites are used in SMFL. After fighting with it for sometime, I have come up with a code with some pointers inside but still could not get what I want.

Here is what I have in the int main()

```
vector<sf::Sprite> sprites;
vector<sf::Texture> textures;

// Load sprites
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "pink_sq.png");
    textures.push_back(texture);
    vector <sf::Texture>::iterator it = textures.begin() + i;
    sf::Sprite sprite(*it);
    sprite.setPosition(i*100,i*100);
    sprites.push_back(sprite);
}
// Start the game loop
while (window.isOpen())
{
    window.clear();

    // Draw the sprite
    for(int i=0;i<sprites.size();i++)
        window.draw(sprites[i]);

    window.display();
}
```

What I am getting is only third square at (200,200) is pink. The other two are white. Somehow textures are not copied to first two sprites.

I know for this simple code, I can avoid vectors, but this code is just for demonstration. I will be using possibly 100s of sprites in the future. Let me know if you guys have an idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a map for your textures? It seems to not work no matter what i try with a vector, the functionality dosn't change much with a map. I usually use maps when dealing with sprites, because you can have a string as your index if you so choose, which can make your code easier to follow.

```
#include <map>
.
.
.
     vector<sf::Sprite> sprites;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    map<int, sf::Texture> textures;

// Load sprites
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        textures[i].loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "pink_sq.png");
        sprites.push_back(sprite);// loads a dummy sprite for a pushback
        sprites[i].setTexture(textures[i]);
        sprites[i].setPosition(i*100,i*100);

}
// Start the game loop
while (window.isOpen())
{

       window.clear();
    // Draw the sprite
    for(int i=0;i<sprites.size();i++){
            window.draw(sprites[i]);
            window.display();
            sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(30)); // so the loop dosn't crash the program randomly
}


}
```

this way produces 3 pink boxes

hope this helps

p.s. still tinkering with the vector, will add to the post if i can find a way.